# Attempts at repeated flagging should fail earlier (if at all)

Tags: bug, flagging, user-interface

I flagged a question for moderator attention. After exchanging some more comments with the OP, I wanted to add something to my remarks to the moderators, so I chose "flag" and "in need of moderator intervention" again and wrote some more remarks. Only when I tried to submit them did I get the red error message saying that I'd already flagged for moderator attention and can't do it again.

- This failure should have occurred earlier, before I took the time to write the remarks.
- I think it shouldn't occur at all, since it may well be useful to add further remarks later.

Comment: You are probably aware of this, but it is worth mentioning that [Math Mods' Office](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/20352/math-mods-office) is a good place for comments like: "I have flagged this and now I have realized that..." (So there is at least some possibility to communicate additional information to mods, although it is probably less visible than a flag. It is difficult to quantify how much attention a message there gets from the moderators - I do not know how intensively they monitor the activity in this room.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak: No, thanks, I didn't know about that! (I was away from the site for a couple of years, and a lot of things seem to have happened in the meantime that I haven't caught up with yet.)

Comment: On the second point: there is a trade-off there, of course it can be useful, but it can also be abused and then be annoying for the moderators. For the first point: I agree and will only add that the "obvious" fix of disabling "flag" does not work as some different flags can be raised in parallel.

Comment: @quid: True, but the radio button for "in need of moderator intervention" could be disabled if this form of flag has already been used.

Comment: It would be certainly possible to disable it in someway. But changing that window could be more "expensive" than disabling the button, but I really do not know enough to say.

Answer (score 4):

This was reported last year (in a slightly different context): [Raising a moderator attention flag in addition to a spam/offensive flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/237744). It indeed appears to be a bug: the radio button should be grayed out & annotated in red if that option is no longer available. This is how all other options work already: "spam", "rude/abusive", "very low quality", "not an answer" (for answers)...

[image: example]

I disagree with the second part

> I think it shouldn't occur at all, since it may well be useful to add further remarks later.

Moderator time is precious. You get one shot at explaining a situation to them; make it count. Same logic applies to exchanging messages through moderator channels.